# Enforce foreign key constraint in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I can't get the foreign key constraint to be enforced using GORM in the Postgres database.

That is, when I define these models:

```
type CrocodileIdentity struct {
    Id               string           `gorm:"primary_key" sql:"type:UUID"`
    CrocodileID      string
    Crocodile        Crocodile        `gorm:"foreignKey:CrocodileID;references:ID"`
}


type Crocodile struct {
    ID    string      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key" sql:"type:UUID"`
    Email string      `json:"email" sql:"type:varchar(255)" gorm:"not null"`
}
```

I cannot see the foreign key constraint in the `CrocodileIdentity` table for the column `CrocodileID`.

Furthermore, I can insert into the `CrocodileIdentity` table without receiving a `foreign key constraint validation error`.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction as to what am I doing wrong in terms of setting up a one to many relation between `CrocodileIdentity` and `Crocodile` using GORM?

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Do you have a foreign key in your Postgres Database ? How did you created the schema? Make sure that there is a foreign key. GORM doesn't handle foreign keys, but database.

Comment: That would be a relatively big bummer if GORM does not create the correct schema out of the model I specify. In other words, I expect that if I specify `gorm:"foreignKey:CrocodileID;references:ID"` that the foreign key constraint will be enforced.

Comment: How do you create your tables?